# Displaying addresses (point) relative to quantity at address using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, address

I just geocoded 40,000 plus addresses.

However there are several addresses that have 100's of people living at a given address (ex. apartment building).

How do I show larger values as larger symbols using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop...sorry for mentioning that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dissolve your points based on a common field, address for instance, if all the 100s are the same address. Then, you can apply a stats field, count in this instance, giving you the total number of times an address is used. Join your counts table, to your features your are symbolizing, and symbolize size-wise based on count

Comment: Thank you, Maksim. Do you have a suggested "how to" resource for me to follow so I can complete this task?

Comment: Dissolve tool: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm Then a simple join

Comment: Cool, if you can accept my answer. Glad to help!

Comment: So I just realized that in my dissolved result there are several address that were matched incorrectly. For example, when using the "identify" tool it shows two different "matching addresses" (matching addresses are result of using ArcGIS online geocoding) and the point is at one of the addresses but it may not be at the actual address. Any advice on how to correct this issue?

Comment: That would be a different question, but you should use the most accurate results, the output should give which locator was used to match. Look for a street address or point locator

Comment: So do I need to look for the most accurate street address in the matching output or the dissolved output. I guess I would like to know if I have to regeocode the addresses in order to get the most accurate results when I use dissolve again...